# Generate List of Data from different sheets in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007

Here's the thing, I want to display a list of data from different sheets in excel file

Ex:

**Sheet 1**:

```
  |       A       |     B 
--|---------------|--------------
1 | Payee:        |  Pedro  
2 | Check Number: |  15263  
3 | Date:         |  12/05/2016
```

**Sheet 2**:

```
  |       A       |     B
--|---------------|--------------
1 | Payee:        |  Juan  
2 | Check Number: |  15685  
3 | Date:         |  12/06/2016
```

and So on

Then in final sheet Display :

```
CheckNumber  
15263  
15685
```

I tried different formulas like `VLOOKUP`, `INDIRECT`, still I can't find answers.
Copy paste is not an option because I want it to be dynamic

Hope you guys Help

Comment: Your data structure is not clear. Is there only one check number on each sheet? Is it always in cell A2 on each sheet? Why do you place A2 to the right of A1? That is not how Excel does it and it is confusing.

Comment: yes, all the data in "Check  number" is in B2, so i want to display all the check number in list form ,@teylyn

Answer (score 0):

**Assupmtions**:
**1.** Name of the sheets of your workbook are Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, and so on....
**2.** `Check Number` is always in `Cell B2` of all sheets.

Enter the following formula in the second row of the column you want to list down `Check Number` and copy/drag it down(say `Column B`).

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet"&ROW()-1&"!"&"$B$2")
```

This will give you following output:

[image]

Comment: Actually My tab have different names, your solution is applicable too but How about tabs with different name, thanks by the way

Comment: @MolarBear - Can you store all the sheet names some where in any of the sheet? Or if there are fixed number or sheets this can be hard coded.

Comment: @MolarBear - Or else are you open to VBA solution?

Answer (score 0):

Actually i find a code here :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc793964.aspx

i tried it and it works, though i use VBA because i cant find a formula for it